# How to find number of unordered non negative integral solutions of the equation?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I find number of unordered non-negative integral solutions of the following equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_r = n.$$
For example, the number of required solutions of $x_1 + x_2 = 3$ will be $2$, namely $(\{3,0\},\{1,2\})$.
I know how to find ordered integral solutions, but is there a way to find unordered solutions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Divide the number of ordered solutions by  $|S_r|$.